# Solidity transfer function

Tags: solidity, remix

when calling the withdraw function , where does the value of (address(this).balance) go ?

```
contract Fallback {

 mapping(address => uint) public contributions;
 address public owner;

 constructor() {
   owner = msg.sender;
   contributions[msg.sender] = 1000 * (1 ether);
 }

 modifier onlyOwner {
       require(
           msg.sender == owner,
           "caller is not the owner"
       );
       _;
   }

 function contribute() public payable {
   require(msg.value < 0.001 ether);
   contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
   if(contributions[msg.sender] > contributions[owner]) {
     owner = msg.sender;
   }
 }

 function getContribution() public view returns (uint) {
   return contributions[msg.sender];
 }

 function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
   payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
 }

 receive() external payable {
   require(msg.value > 0 && contributions[msg.sender] > 0);
   owner = msg.sender;
 }
}
```

Comment: `payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);` initiates a transfer of `address(this).balance` eth to `payable(owner)`. `owner` is set in the constructor as the `msg.sender`.

Answer (score 0):

The function is sending the balance of the contract to the owner address. If we look at the constructor:

```
 constructor() {
   owner = msg.sender;
   contributions[msg.sender] = 1000 * (1 ether);
 }
```

We can notice that the owner is set to msg.sender. In other words, the eth is transferred to the person who have minted the contract.

Answer (score 0):

the value is being redirected to the address that minted the contract.

```
 constructor() {
   **owner = msg.sender;**
   contributions[msg.sender] = 1000 * (1 ether);
 }
```

the constructor is a function automatically executed at the creation of the contract, this is how you get to define the "owner" public variable.